# How to merge changes from Subversion Trunk to Branch and open editor to resolve conflicts

Tags: windows, batch-file, svn

I am working on a svn branch and using the following batch file to get regular changes from Trunk into my branch.  When conflicts emerge I want the batch file to open my merge editor when I choose option (e).

I run this from a path that contains the trunk and branches

`svn update trunk 
 svn update branches 
 svn merge https://URL/trunk branches/MYBRANCH`

When a conflict occurs I get the usual:

--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r470 through r475 into > 'branches\MYBRANCH':
 G   branches\MYBRANCH
Summary of conflicts:
  Text conflicts: 1
Conflict discovered in file 'branches\MYBRANCH\source\blabla\blabla.lang'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) show diff, (e) edit file, (m) merge,
        (mc) my side of conflict, (tc) their side of conflict,
        (s) show all options: e

Does anyone know what I need in my batch file in order to open an editor with the relevant files?

Using "--accept edit" opens the tool, but does not pre-select the affected files.

[image: TortoiseMerge opens, but asks for the files to compare/merge]

Comment: Did you try to use the `--accept edit` option with `svn merge` command ?

Comment: Hi Laurent H,  adding that to the command line does launch the editor I selected (TortoiseMerge) but unfortunately it seems to be asking for the file... there must be some other settings or args so that automatically opens the affected files.  P.S. Clicking OK on the dialog above does not open the conflicted/merge target.

Comment: Did you try to use the `--accept launch` option with `svn merge` command ?

Comment: That does not work either.  I'm beginning to think that its just not possible to call a single batch file that will perform a svn merge and launch an editor with the affected file/s automatically if conflicts exist.